# Proposition 7.8. of Adkins' Algebra

Tags: group-theory

I don't understand some of the following text (from Adkins' Algebra):

[image]

1- Why "If $q > p$ then $1 + kq | p^2$ for some $k \ge 0$"? Possibly there is some relevance with $|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum [G:C(a)]$; if so I can't derive $|G|=1+kq$.

2- Why "Since $q > p$, this can only occur if $k = 0$ or $1 + kq = p^2$? For example suppose $n^2 \times (1 + kq) = p^2$. Then $n^2 kq = (p-n)(p+n)$ and then $q=p+n$ and $n^2 k=p-n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question follows from the third Sylow theorem: the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups is congruent to $1$ mod $q$ (hence, the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups is $1 + kq$ for some positive $k$), and the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups divides the index of a Sylow $q$-subgroup in $G$, which in this case is $p^2$ (as $\# G = p^2 q$, and a Sylow $q$-subgroup has order $q$).

To answer the second question, if $q > p$, then $1 + kq > p$ if $k > 0$. If $k = 0$, $1 + kq\mid p^2$. If $k > 0$, then $1 + kq > p$, and $1 + kq$ divides $p^2$, so $1 + kq$ must be $p^2$ (the only divisors of $p^2$ are $1$, $p$, and $p^2$).

Answer (score 0):

We have that $p^2=n(1+kq)$ (possible with $k=0$ and $n=p^2.$) Since $p$ is prime the factors of $p^2$ are $1,p$ and $p^2.$ So, it must be $1+kq=1$ (equivalently, $k=0$), $1+kq=p$ or $1+kq=p^2.$ But if $k\ge 1$ we have $p=1+kq>q>p,$ which is not possible. Thus, when $k>0$ the only possibility is  $1+kq=p^2.$